# Cant zoom on apple device and Samsung S3 error

Tags: iphone, ipad, zooming, viewport

i currently developing [this site](http://sell-your-power.com/web/www), my problem is than user cannot zoom page on mobile devices. (Ipad,Iphone..) And user saw only part of the website when website load on Samsung S3. I Tried to search, but i dont saw answer what can help me.

I think than problem is in metatay "viewport".
Actually i have this.

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1050px; user-scalable=yes; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Thanks for any suggestion :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested. I fixed like this, i just edit width and delete another tags.

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1136px">
```